# Windows 8.1 thinks that my Visual Studio 2010 Shortcut is called Sql Data Tools

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, shortcuts, visual-studio-2010, start-screen

When I go into the Start screen, I have a tile for Visual Studio.
However, it is not called Visual Studio 2010 but Sql Data Tools.

I then proceeded to remove it from the tiles and went to my desktop and created a shortcut to Visual Studio 2010.
Then I right clicked on my shortcut and "pinned it to start", but it keeps using the wrong name.

How do I manually rename it in the Start screen?

Comment: As far as I know, you can rename tiles without using a program such as OblyTile to create them in the first place. Are you absolutely sure that the program you are pinning is the one you want?

Answer (score 1):

Right the way I did it was....

Copy a new shortcut lnk to the location (use win+r to open a run command box)

```
shell:start menu\programs
```

It won't appear in all apps under the right location, but you pin it to the start and search for it as expected.